# NUGET update packages from command line to VSTS

Tags: c#, .net, nuget-package, azure-artifacts

I had created private nuget feed inside my VSTS. Initially, i pushed 4 nuget packages from commandline to VSTS without any issues.

Now, i am trying to update few packages with the latest updates. But, getting the below error to update inside VSTS feed.

**Commands i used to update my feeds with VSTS**

```
nuget.exe push -Source "xxx.Shared.Nuget" -ApiKey VSTS xxx.Infra.Design.Patterns.1.0.3.nupkg
```

Please provide credentials for:

> nuget.exe push -Source "xxx.Shared.Nuget" -ApiKey VSTS
>   xxx.Infra.Design.Patterns.1.0.3.nupkg
>       Please provide credentials for: https://xxx.pkgs.visualstudio.com/_packaging/xxx.Shared.Nuget/nuget/v3/index.json

I am receiving below error for the above command

> The specified source 'xxx.Shared.Nuget' is invalid. Please provide a
>   valid source.

Please note that, i had changed my nuget version from 1.0.2 to 1.0.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is if we add a nuget package url to visual studio and after that if you give different name while creating and adding url to command line, this error occurs. I fixed this error by giving the same url what i have given to visual studio during package url integration, Then, it started working.

Answer (score 0):

That error means NuGet is unable to find a source with key `xxx.Shared.NuGet` in NuGet.config. The quickest way to fix that is by running [nuget sources add -Name `xxx.Shared.NuGet` -Source `url-to-your-vsts-feed`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/tools/cli-ref-sources). You can find a pre-created version of this command in the Connect to Feed dialog. See [steps 1 and 2 of this walkthrough](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/package/nuget/publish).

Comment: Thanks Alex for your answer. Yes, the problem is if we add a nuget package url to visual studio and after that if you give different name while creating and adding url to command line, this error occurs. I fixed this error by giving the same url what i have given to visual studio during package url integration, Then, it started working.

Comment: Glad you got it fixed :)